# Plot an equation with matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot an equation where the `x` axis represents time `t` and the `y` axis represents a variable `n`.  Now the formula for `n` is `n =((np.log(t)*10**6)/np.log(2)) + 1` and the maximum time on my graph is the time since big bang theory in seconds which is `4.35 x 10**17 seconds`.

I tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def graph(formula, x_range):  
    y = np.array(x_range)  
    x = eval(formula)
    plt.plot(x,y)  
    plt.show() 

graph(((np.log(x)*10**6)/np.log(2)) + 1, range(0, 4.35*10**17 ))
```

which doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: `eval` works on a `string`. Nevertheless it is not seen as very elegant anyway.

Comment: *Time since big bang theory* is maximum 90000 seconds nowadays. *Time since big bang* may be considerably larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- The range is supposed to be defined **over integers**;
- The number of items the range would generate **is too large, you have to take huge steps**;
- The formula takes `x` as a variable, but you seem to define a `np.array(x_range)` **in `y`**; and more importantly
- you use `eval(..)`, but `eval(..)` **usually a string** or another object that can be *parsed*;
- you do not give `graph(..)` a formula as first element: before Python calls `graph(..)` it **first evaluates the operands**.

In my opinion, the best way to achieve this is using a *lambda-expression*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def graph(formula, x_range):  
    x = np.array(x_range)
    #^ use x as range variable
    y = formula(x)
    #^          ^call the lambda expression with x
    #| use y as function result
    plt.plot(x,y)  
    plt.show() 

graph(lambda x : ((np.log(x)*10**6)/np.log(2)) + 1, range(0, 435*10**15,10**12))
#     ^use a lambda expression                               ^range over integers
#                                                             take huge steps
```

This generates the following image:

[image]

**EDIT**:

based on your comment you want time on the *y*-axis and the function on the *x*-axis, this can simply be achieved by **assigning** to the other variables like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def graph(formula, x_range):  
    y = np.array(x_range)
    x = formula(y)
    plt.plot(x,y)  
    plt.show() 

graph(lambda x : ((np.log(x)*10**6)/np.log(2)) + 1, range(0,435*10**15,10**12))
```

Note that you do not need to change the name of the variable in the lambda-expression: indeed when you call the lambda expression, the *local* `x` will simply be the `y` of the caller.

Comment: I realise that maybe time `t` being on the `y` axis makes more sense. How would you flip it such that time is on `y` axis and n is on the `x` axis.

Comment: @WasswaSamuel: simply rename `x`, `y` and `y` `x` in the **assignment** in the function. Will edit the answer.